# Getting compile errors on Eclipse from Bean shell files

Tags: java, android, eclipse, javabeans

What is the correct way to import Java bean shell files into Eclipse?  I want to use eval so I copied the files from an app that my friend paid for but he did not get the source files.  Anyway, when I did that,  I got so many errors like 'syntax error on token interface', 'implicit super constructor undefined', 'constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor', and a bunch of other errors.  Any help you give is appreciated.

Comment: Most of them will be chained errors. i.e. if you find out the underlying issue, the other errors will go away because the initial *major* issue has got Eclipse into a twisted state

Comment: OK, thanks.  After so much more googling, I think I put it in the wrong library.